# "On Error GoTo" ignored when searching for second horizontal axis

Tags: excel, vba

NOTE: the code below actually works! See my own answer on the cause of the issue I was having. I decided to leave the code here since I have seen other questions regarding how to delete second horizontal axis.

THE INITIAL QUESTION/ISSUE: I'm formating a series of spreadsheets that have multiple charts on them. When applying the chosen chart style (I'm using style 209 - with a code line "ActiveChart.ChartStyle = 209), some charts come back with two horizontal axis, which I don't want (some charts have two vertical axis - but that is OK). Instead of going chart by chart and manually deleting each secondary horizontal axis, I included a piece of code on my formating subroutine. The code works most of the time. But sometimes I get the error below:

[VB error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJy9R.jpg)

The impression I have is that the "On Error GoTo" is being "ignored". I.e. the error above happens when I get to "ActiveChart.SetElement..." line, as the chart has no secondary axis. This means that the line where I asked for the secondary axis' maximum scale (i.e., "chart_axis = ...") must have returned an error (as the secondary axis doesn't exist). Which means that the "On Error GoTo" was ignored (or didn't jump to "No_second_axis").

Here is the part of the code I'm using that deletes the second axis (if it exists):

```
    Dim s_name As String
    Dim chart_axis As Variant

    For Each Shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        s_name = Shape.Name
        If Shape.Type = msoChart Then
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(s_name).Activate
            On Error GoTo No_second_axis
    'Try to get the "scale" of secondary horizontal axis - error if non-existent                
    chart_axis = ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MaximumScale
         'If it reached this line, there was no error when getting the second horizontal axis scale (i.e., the second horizontal axis exists. No I can delete it!
         With ActiveChart
            ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementSecondaryCategoryAxisNone)
         End With
    No_second_axis:
        End If
    Next Shape

    End Sub
```

Am I missing something? Why does the "On Error Go To" appears to work sometimes but doesn't work for some charts? I can't find a "pattern" in terms of which type of chart it works with vs. a type of chart it doesn't work with.

Comment: In general, VBA is rather buggy when it comes to charts selected objects. I as a first step define a `ChartObject` object from the active sheet and drill down from there. Also, I think there is a way to test for a secondary axis without needed an `On Error` catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an extra couple of hours struggling with this issue, I decided to inspect each chart before running the sub. Using "Go To" on Excel (shortcut = F5) and selecting "objects", I could cycle through each object (by pressing TAB). What I realized is that I had some "hidden" charts (i.e., very old charts that were somehow minimized/collapsed into a obscure place in the spreadsheet). These charts had no "series" on them. For some reason, the "chart_axis = ..." part of the code above can read a secondary horizontal axis scale, but the axis really doesn't exist (as I get an error when trying to delete such axis). Maybe this is a bug on Excel or there is a logical explanation for it - but this is beyond what I need for now. I decided to answer my own question in case this example helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is a generic Office error that suggests something went wrong under the hood.

To try and avoid this error I would try the following:

Use `Application.ScreenUpdating=false` in the beginning of the function (and then `Application.ScreenUpdating=true` in the end). This helped me avoid rendering problems in the when updating a large number of objects/shapes in an Office document.

OR

Use `Application.ScreenUpdating=false` in the beginning of every iteration of your Shape object loop and then use `Application.ScreenUpdating=true` after updating it.

Hopefully you will be able to spot which of the charts creates a problem and under which circumstances (or state).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions (and quick response time!) - please see my own answer above. As you mentioned, this is for sure a "under the hood" error.